# Who was the first to use right and left ideals in a ring?

Tags: math-history

I know Emmy Noether defined the terms right and left ideal of a ring and made extensive use of them. However, I am interested in knowing whether someone had already coined the term (in the very precise way in which she used it) before her. I do not mean Kummer's and Dedekind's somewhat different meaning in number theory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/35305/39640) contains what you are looking for.